# Optional URL variables

Tags: python, url-routing, flask

Is there a way to define URLs with optional URL params in Flask? Essentially, what I'd like to do is define rules that allow for optionally specified languages:

```
/
/de -> matches / (but doesn't collide with /profile)
/profile 
/de/profile
```

I think I've figured out a way to do it, but it involves either making a change to how Werkzeug and Flask handles the request (either monkey patching or forking the framework source). This seems like an overly complex way to deal with this problem though.. Is there an easier way to do this that I'm overlooking?

**Edit:**

Based on Brian's answer, here's what I came up with:

**app.py**:

```
from loc import l10n

def create_app(config):                                                                                                                 
    app = Flask(__name__)                                                                                                               
    app.config.from_pyfile(config)                                                                                                      

    bp = l10n.Blueprint()                                                                                                               
    bp.add_url_rule('/', 'home', lambda lang_code: lang_code)                                                                           
    bp.add_url_rule('/profile', 'profile', lambda lang_code: 'profile: %s' % 
        lang_code)
    bp.register_app(app)                                                                                                                

    return app  

if __name__ == '__main__':
    create_app('dev.cfg').run()
```

**loc/l10ln.py**

```
class Blueprint(Blueprint_):
    def __init__(self):
        Blueprint_.__init__(self, 'loc', __name__)

    def register_app(self, app):
        app.register_blueprint(self, url_defaults={'lang_code': 'en'})                                                                  
        app.register_blueprint(self, url_prefix='/<lang_code>')

        self.app = app
```

(I haven't gotten to pulling `lang_code` from the variable list yet, but will be doing that shortly)

Now that's just hot imho.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Blueprints might work for this, since they can be registered multiple times.

```
from flask import Flask, Blueprint

app = Flask(__name__)
bp = Blueprint('main', __name__)

@bp.route('/')
def hello(lang):
    return 'Hello ' + lang + '!'

app.register_blueprint(bp, url_defaults={'lang': 'en'})
app.register_blueprint(bp, url_prefix='/<lang>')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

If that works, see [Internationalized Blueprint URLs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/urlprocessors/#internationalized-blueprint-urls) in the Flask documentation for a way to avoid specifying a `lang` argument in every view function.

Comment: Definitely the way to go imho, given the (relative) new hotness of blueprints

Comment: Can you give me better example ? I want to have always, mysite.com/en and mysite.com/ka also give translated messages from database with method to template by {{ translations.any_record_from_database }}

Answer (score 10):

Just in case you didn't know, you can register multiple routes for a view. Might be a pain to do it for every view, but it's doable...

```
DEFAULT_LANG = 'en'

@app.route('/profile')
@app.route('/<lang>/profile')
def profile(lang=DEFAULT_LANG):
   pass
```

Or, perhaps you could implement your own `route` decorator that automatically invokes `app.route` for both scenarios...

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

DEFAULT_LANG = 'en'

def lang_route(rule, **options):
    def decorator(f):
        endpoint = options.pop('endpoint', None)
        app.add_url_rule(rule, endpoint, f, **options)
        app.add_url_rule('/<lang>%s' % rule, endpoint, f, **options)
        return f
    return decorator

@lang_route('/profile') # also accepts '/<lang>/profile' automatically
def profile(lang=DEFAULT_LANG):
    return lang

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: I think this is a great and extremely thorough answer.

Comment: This isn't a bad solution, but I think that blueprints are more correct since they're designed to encapsulate a set of routes, and let you easily manipulate all those routes at once. The [Flask docs recommend](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/urlprocessors/#internationalized-application-urls) using blueprints for URL internationalization: "You can further improve that by writing your own decorator that prefixes URLs with the language code, but the more beautiful solution is using a blueprint."

Comment: @BrianMarshall, I +1'd your answer... good info at the link you provided.

Comment: +1 I didn't know you could have multiple routes for a view! Super helpful.

Comment: Thanks for this. This falls apart though when you do an ``app.route('/<lang>')`` because it collides with ``app.route('/profile')``. Of course, I could use a URL re-write to get around that, but it didn't seem right to depend on external tech to get around something like this. Blueprints in @BrianMarshall's answer is definitely the way to go based on what I've seen.

Comment: Hello, Can you put full example ?  with html switching languages ?

Comment: please share if you found the full example